# HttpPost request not working when JSON string has HTML in

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, http-post, httpclient, dotnet-httpclient

If this is a duplicate of any existing question, please let me know which post has a similar situation.

I am trying to call a POST API, which actually works perfectly from REST clients like POSTMAN.

When I try to call that API from C# using `HttpClient`, it only works if I do not use any HTML content in the request body.

Here is my code:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
string baseUrl = channel.DomainName;
client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseUrl);

client.DefaultRequestHeaders
        .TryAddWithoutValidation(
            "Content-Type",
            "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8");

const string serviceUrl = "/api/create";

var jsonString = CreateApiRequestBody(model, userId, false);

var uri = new Uri(baseUrl + serviceUrl);
try
{
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(uri.ToString(), new StringContent(jsonString, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        Stream receiveStream = response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result;
        StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8);
        var str = readStream.ReadToEnd();
    }
    ...
}
```

And my `jsonString` looks like:

```
{
    \"user_id\":\"6\",
    \"description\":\"<h2 style=\\\"font-style:italic;\\\"><u><font><font>Test Test Test&nbsp;</font></font></u></h2>\\n\\n<p style=\\\"font-style: italic;\\\">Hi it&#39;s a Test JOB</p>\\n\\n<p>&nbsp;</p>\"
}
```

When I use plain text in **`description`** tag, the API returns a valid response, but not with the HTML content in it.

I believe I might be missing some extra header or something else.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried setting both content-type and accept-type as application/json ?

Comment: use content type to application/josn Content-Type: application/json

Comment: I tried with,  client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", "application/json"); and it did not work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using `WebUtility.HtmlEncode()` method?

Where you're setting the `StringContent` content, try using `WebUtility.HtmlEncode(jsonString)` to make it API-friendly.

Like this:

```
using System.Net;

HttpResponseMessage response =
    await client.PostAsync(
               uri.ToString(),
               new StringContent(WebUtility.HtmlEncode(jsonString),
                                 Encoding.UTF8,
                                "application/json"));
```

Don't forget to use `System.Net`

That will give you a safe (especially for APIs) HTML string to use in your request.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry that didn't help.

The only other suggestion I have is to use the `StringContent()` method passing in only `WebUtility.HtmlEncode(jsonString)`; excluding the Encoding and mediaType.

Let me know if you have any luck.

Comment: HI, thanks for your answer. The actual issue was with the third party API that I was using. They were filtering out the html content basically. After lot of discussion and reaching out to the actual developer, I have found this.

Comment: Always best if you can speak to the developer. I tend to find support aren't much use. Hope you manage to get it sorted :) best regards